# Tensorboard image summary in canned estimators?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying add my own image summaries:

```
class CustomMonitor(tf.contrib.learn.monitors.BaseMonitor):
    def step_begin(self, step):
        if step % 1500 == 0:
            img = estimator.predict({'x': X})
            tf.summary.image('img-' + str(step), img)

    def step_end(self, step, output):
        pass

# ...

estimator.fit(input_fn=get_input_fn, monitors=[CustomMonitor()])
```

This raises an error:

```
raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
   RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Any way to log anything to Tensorboard when using a pre-made estimator?

Comment: Are you trying to create the summary inside your training loop ? That doesn't work in Tensorflow. Summaries are defined as nodes in the computation graph before starting training. What you should do is RUN your summary operations every 1500 steps. Not CREATE them.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Can I run a summary op from a different session as the training op?

Comment: I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to create two sessions that use the same graph. However, I don't see any reason why you would want to do that either. What's preventing you from using the same session for both ?